# i can't figure out the logic behind update or delete pages using jquery and codeigniter

Tags: php, html, jquery, codeigniter, controller

all three components (the view and it's jquery functions and controller) doesn't work and i tried a lot .. any help ?
i got this "all users" view
it has a loop of all users
And at the same page i have a jquery just to go to controller that load "updateProfile" view of the required id in the view
Then , in the specified controller i got the function editProfileByID()

i tried to pass userid to controller through jquery $.post method , and it works the controller received it , but it won't move to the update view with processed data

```
<td align="center">
  <a class="editProfile" rel="<?= $row['id'] ?>" href="#">
    <img src="<?= base_url() ?>images/operations.JPG" width="50" height="50">
  </a>
</td>
```

and at the same page i have a jquery just to go to controller that load "updateProfile" view of the required id in the view , like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editProfile').click(function() {
                        var id = $(this).attr('rel');
                        $.post("<?= base_url() ?>index.php/Users/editProfileByID", {
                            id: id,
                        }, function(data) {
                            if (data != "0") {
                                alert(data);
                            } else {
 
                            }
                        });
});
```

then , in the specified controller i got this function :

```
function editProfileByID()
    {
        $userID = $this->input->post('id');
        $whereArray = array('id' => $userID);
        $data['adminData'] = $this->user_model->get_user_by($whereArray);
        $data['main_content'] = 'usersViews/editProfile';
        $data['page_title'] = 'Edit Profile';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
        return "success";
    }
```

Comment: What does `echo $data;` right before load->view() prints out. Also why do you need to return "success" when you are trying to load view? I would remove it. Also you would want to have 2 separate functions, one which would help you load and other which would acutally edit the profile and there you can return "success" or "failed".

Comment: @Adi yes you are right that is what i am planning.
but the problem is in the first part "load update view" with specified record
i removed "return" line in the controller. i put it just to trace the code.
when i alert data in jquery , it gets html code of the desired update view page.

Comment: Then you need to backtrack a little bit, firstly debug by just loading view directly without passing any params or placing the load->view() at the top, also is "includes/template" is template the html file you are trying to load?

Comment: *editProfileById()* loads the view, but then it must be returned to the caller who must show/manage it

Comment: @Adi i figured it out finally , 
all i have to do is to adjust editProfileByID() Method in the controller to receive a parameter that becomes editProfileByID(userID)
then i edit the view html by adding value to href attribute to the controller method and pass parameter to it.
<a class="editProfile" href="<?= base_url() ?>index.php/Users/editProfileByID/<?= $row['id'] ?>">
</a>
and remove any jquery code.
and it worked fine.
.... 
lesson learned --> passing data from view to controller without using post request or S.post method in jquery.

Comment: Oh yes that's one way of doing it as well. Good to hear you got it figured out.